# Python serial.read() doesn't read data from Arduino in the first loop

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, pyserial

I am a hardware design engineer trying to play with high-level-languages recently. These are my first Python codes. I am very far from OOP and all high-level-language shenanigans. I loved Python very much but I am at the very beginning of learning it. Thanks for your help in advance.

I am trying to read serial data from Arduino. This code is running on Raspberry Pi 3+. It doesn't read in the first loop.

Here is the Arduino code that sends dummy data upon request:

```
String data = "";
void setup(){
 
  Serial.begin(115200);
}
 
void loop(){
 
  while (Serial.available() > 0) {
    data = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
     if(data=="$ACONSP?"){
      Serial.println("$ACONSP,3600,100,100,200,300,400,500,600,700");
      }
      else if (data == "$ASTAT"){
      Serial.println("$ASTAT,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0");
      }
      else if (data == "$AENV"){
      Serial.println("$AENV,234.2,49.3,27.7,41.6,24.9,39.9,0,0");
      }
  }
}
```

Here is the Python code that sends request and read the response from Arduino and write it into SQLite.

```
from time import sleep
import serial

PowerResponseKeys = ['head','timePassed','Ch0Consp','Ch1Consp','Ch2Consp','Ch3Consp','Ch4Consp','Ch5Consp','Ch6Consp','Ch7Consp']
StatusResponseKeys = ['head','Ch0Stat','Ch1Stat','Ch2Stat','Ch3Stat','Ch4Stat','Ch5Stat','Ch6Stat','Ch7Stat']
EnvironmentResponseKeys = ['head','Voltage','Frequency','InTemp','InHumidity','ExtTemp','ExtHumidity','DoorSwitch','DoorRelay']
channel = ["A","B","C"]
request_type = ["CONSP?", "STAT", "ENV"]
ser = serial.Serial("/dev/cu.usbserial-1420", baudrate=115200, timeout=0)
counter = 0

#The function that sends the "requestline= "$"+channel+request_type" string to Arduino and read the response
def request(channel,request_type):
    line = ''
    responseKey = []
    requestline= "$"+channel+request_type
    if request_type == 'CONSP?':
        responseKey = PowerResponseKeys
    elif request_type == 'STAT':
        responseKey = StatusResponseKeys
    elif request_type == 'ENV':
        responseKey = EnvironmentResponseKeys
    else:
        pass
    ser.write(requestline.encode())
    sleep(2)
    if ser.inWaiting() > 0:
        line = str(ser.readline().decode('ascii').strip()).split(",")
    response_dict = dict(zip(responseKey, line))
    return response_dict
```

If I write this: `if len(request(channel[0], request_type[0])) > 0:` if statement, it waits for sometime and return the right response. But it waits for a long time.

```
while 1:
    if counter < 2:
        if len(request(channel[0], request_type[0])) > 0:
            Write2DB(request(channel[0], request_type[0]))
        else:
            pass
        counter += 1
    else:
       break:
```

If I do `if counter < 1:` instead of `if counter < 2:`, it doesn't return anything. So I think it is all about "not getting the response string on time"

This loop needed to loop many times:

```
while True:
    if counter <3:
        request(channel[0],request_type[0])
    else:
        break
```

If I change the `sleep(2)` to `sleep(1)` or a lesser value, it never reads the response from Arduino.

What I need is, reading the response from Arduino faster, in the first loop if it is possible without waiting more than 2-3 seconds. I've read the serial library documentation, but couldn't figure out what solves my problem.

I assume some kind of handshake between Python and Arduino will solve the problem but am not sure.

What do you recommend? What should I do?

Thanks again.

Comment: new USB connection resets some Arduinos and the Arduino then waits some seconds in bootloader for upload

Comment: How can I test if it is the case? I am using Arduino Nano, Arduino 328P (Old bootloader) Hmm, it says old bootloder. Let me try with a different one and get back.

Comment: Nano resets on new USB connection. doesn't matter what bootloader or any. the auto reset circuit is on the USB chip. new bootloader (Optiboot) waits shorter time for upload (because is set for auto reset and not a manual reset by user)

Comment: @Juraj thank you, I didn't know that. I'll try with regular setup.

Comment: @Juraj did not work. In addition, as I install it on custom board without USB chip, I still have problems. The data I read is not well in first couple of seconds. I'll open a new question with details and share the link here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed `timeout=0` to `timeout=1` and it solved the problem.

```
ser = serial.Serial("/dev/cu.usbserial-1420", baudrate=115200, timeout=0)
```